# Sentence with (으)면 하다 in past tense

Tags: grammar, translation

I came across this sentence from a text message

> 금일 결과 리뷰 했으면 합니다

I found in [my reference](https://books.google.co.kr/books?id=dwaTAgAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=korean%20grammar%20intermediate&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&source=gb_mobile_search&ovdme=1&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=korean%20grammar%20intermediate&f=false) that the pattern (으)면+하다 means "would/wish" and conjugating  하다 in past tense provide a more assertive tone.

Therefore I wonder if the sentence above can be translated as

> I would like to review today's results.

Is it correct?

Also, if the sentence above was

> 금일 결과 리뷰 하면 합니다

how would the translation change?

Comment: "하다" in “-었으면 하다“ is an auxiliary verb whose dictionary meaning is as follows: (After a verb or adjective, it is often used in the "-었으면 하다" construction) to express a desire to do the action or be in the state of the preceding word. So  "”리뷰하면 하다" is unnatural. It is interpreted as "If you review it, I will do with you. But if you don’t, I won't do.”

Answer (score 1):

"-했으면 한다" is a polite way of expressing your desire.  The example sentence expresses a "request" to have the results reviewed, and it's not clear who is supposed to do the reviewing.  In some case it may mean "Shouldn't we have a meeting to review this now?"; in other case it could mean "Could you review this?" though "금일 결과 리뷰해 주셨으면 합니다" may be better in that case.

So, depending on the context, I think a better translation is:

> I would like to have today's results reviewed.

or maybe even

> Could you review today's results?

---

On the other hand,

> 금일 결과 리뷰 하면 합니다

This sentence makes no sense to me.  "-했으면 하다" must use past tense.